# Licia of Lindelt dissapeared?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've tried killing Licia without the eye orb, and she wasn't there by like the 3rd time I tried. I've tried walking back and forth from Heides to Majula and back, I've tried exiting the game and returning, but she won't respawn. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Likely the only way to get her back is to talk to [Cromwell the Pardoner](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Cromwell+the+Pardoner), who will (at a cost) remove any sin you have committed (from attacking npc's). The only trouble though is that he is a fair way into the game (he can be found just after the Prowling Magus boss fight), so getting there is a bit of a challenge.

The other possibility is that she might have actually died, and you (should) be able to find her Gravestone in either Majula, where she opens the door to Huntsman's Copse, or near the bonfire where you met her originally.

Comment: Thanks also does it make a difference that i'm on new game+?

Comment: No, ng+ doesn't affect npc spawning or anything like that.